# Adding one more variable to .HTACCESS file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

Here the idea is to make the URL short now this is what the .htacss will do

The real URL is:

```
http://myhost/web/search.php?year=2014
```

The .htaccess will change it to:

```
http://myhost/web/search/2014
```

And this is what .htaccess will look like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule . - [L]


#if search with one variable
RewriteRule ^search/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ search.php?year=$1 [L,NC]
```

Now the idia is her I have tow variable like the real URL is:

```
http://myhost/web/search.php?year=2014&status=1
```

now it should look like:

```
http://myhost/web/search/2014/1
```

So what should I edit on the .htaccess, is it possible with .htaccss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 choices

1 - put second variable inside `.htaccess` file for example :

```
RewriteRule ^search/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+) search.php?year=$1&status=$2 [L,NC] 
RewriteRule ^search/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ search.php?year=$1 [L,NC]
```

2- parse `URL` in php file if you want to catch all variables after `2014/` , using `explode (/)`